# i want distinct refno which is not delivered by the help of sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   datetime              refno      status      final_status


2016-12-01 10:00:00      123456     hold

2016-12-02 11:10:00      123456     delivered 

2016-12-01 10:00:00      654321     hold

2016-12-02 12:20:00      654321     delivered 

2016-12-01 10:00:00      111111     hold

2016-12-01 01:00:00      222222     hold
```

i want distinct refno which is not delivered

I want to output like this:-

output:-

```
    datetime              refno     status    


2016-12-01 10:00:00      111111     hold       

2016-12-01 01:00:00      222222     hold
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

```
SET @refno:=0;
SET @row:=0;
SELECT datetime, refno, status, RN
FROM (
      SELECT datetime,
            case when @refno<>refno then @row:=0 else null end _row_reset,
            @refno as old_refno, 
            @refno:=refno as refno,
            status,
            @row:=@row+1 as RN
      FROM orders
      ORDER BY refno asc, datetime desc
                                                     ) X
WHERE RN=1 AND status<>'delivered'
```

The above query will group your records according to the reference no and then take the latest record for each reference number and check if it's not equal to delivered.

Thanks for the help and suggestions [insac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5077154/insac)

Comment: I think it's correct (assumption: 'delivered' is the final status for the refno ) but I'd suggest you to add a couple of lines to explain what you have done here.

Comment: On second thought... has MySQL analytical functions?

Comment: Tested on [rextester](http://rextester.com/CCT26725). It still complains about ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Now the issue seems to be on the expected result (unless there's some errors on my new test on [rextester](http://rextester.com/MHSWW3934)

Comment: There was an error in my test (date instead of datetime) but the result still is not the expected one: the issue lies in the fact that the @row variable is global and doesn't reste itself for each refno. [Test](http://rextester.com/ETZZ44257)

Comment: I tried working a bit on your approach and the result is [here](http://rextester.com/BZFAPS52787). Can you check it if it's something you'd like to use to complete your answer?

Comment: @Insac I have updated my answer, thanks for the help and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but here's my answer:

```
SELECT order_datetime,order_refno,order_status
 FROM orders o
where not exists (select 1 from orders o1 
                   where order_status='delivered' 
                     and o.order_refno=o1.order_refno)
```

Basically we're scanning the table for all the rows whose refno never appear in a row with "delivered" status.

Warning: it doesn't return you the last status but all the rows of refno that are still not delivered. If you have only "hold" and "delivered" as in your example, that's ok.

You can test it on [rextester](http://rextester.com/FYBP2022)

P.S.: I used slightly different field names as I'm strongly against using reserved keywords as field names.

Answer (score 0):

your query like this

```
select count(*) as item,refno,status,datetime from supply group by refno having item < 2;
+------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| item | refno  | status | datetime            |
+------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|    1 | 111111 | hold   | 2016-12-01 10:00:00 |
|    1 | 222222 | hold   | 2016-12-01 01:00:00 |
+------+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Just in case, like me, someone is not used to this MySQL "non standard" group-by behaviour: yes, it compiles, it works and you can test it [here](http://rextester.com/TZO94639). I still think that some assumptions should be added (e.g. the only statuses are 'hold' and 'delivered')

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Select datetime, refno, status 
from your_table 
where status not in ('delivered')
```

Comment: This will give all the reference ids as output. The output for this query will be `123456,654321,111111,222222`.